# Spark SQL does not run as expected when referencing partition on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, partitioning

I have parquet files on S3 partitioned by a column that is an integer eg . partitionid

When i run my sql query

```
SELECT * FROM parquet.`s3a://path/to/my/partitions/` WHERE partitionid = 784143
```

I expect spark to only read the data in the partition I specified but as it appears it runs a task for each partition what could I be doing wrong ?

The query does run as expected when the partition is specified on the URL but is this correct ?
Does spark not know of the structure of the parquet files when it sees the partition folders ?

Any more info on how Spark handles this would be appreciated , thank you all in advance !